# using rpy in a django app throws RPy_Exception: R Function "get" not found

Tags: django, rpy2, rpython

Here's the traceback(copy pasted):

```
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                    response = middleware_method(request) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/middleware/common.py in process_request
            if (not _is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/middleware/common.py in _is_valid_path
        urlresolvers.resolve(path, urlconf) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in resolve
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in resolve
                    sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in resolve
                    sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in resolve
            return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _get_callback
            self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py in wrapper
        result = func(*args) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in get_callable
                lookup_view = getattr(import_module(mod_name), func_name) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module
    __import__(name) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/harsh/minip-server/website/Video_Performance/views.py in <module>
import datetime,rpy ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rpy.py in <module>
r = R() ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rpy.py in __init__
        self.get = _rpy.get_fun('get')  # this must happen before any calls to self or its methods! ...
▶ Local vars
```

Any clue?

***EDIT***:
Here's the code

```
import rpy
```

don't get me wrong, it's the line the error is coming at. I tried on a separate python prompt and there `import rpy` does not fail. Only in the website it's failing. Why?

Comment: At best I can suggest that there's a problem with your configuration. Note that the stack trace goes down into the library you are trying to import. There may be a clue there as to what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a multhreading issue. Concurrent access to R is bad (in the "don't cross the streams, it would be bad" sense). rpy2 has a locking mechanism that should raise an Exception whenever it is about to happen.

Comment: It is also related to the lack of required stack memory for the selected process. In my case I had to run this command: `ulimit -s unlimited` before spawning the application process. But I would recommend to not leave it as unlimited in production.